# SSIS 2012 Method not found: void

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I recently got this error in every SSIS package (using Visual Studio 2012), when I want to open a OLE DB source component:

```
===================================

Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.DataFlowUI.DataFlowConnectionPage.set_DataPreviewTimeout(Int32)'. (Microsoft Visual Studio)

------------------------------
Program Location:

at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.DataFlowUI.OleDbSourceUI.SetConnectionPageDescriptions(DataFlowConnectionPage connectionPage)
at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.DataFlowUI.DataFlowAdapterUI.AddCommonConnectionPage(DataFlowComponentForm form, String helpKeyword)
at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.DataFlowUI.OleDbSourceUI.AddPagesToForm(DataFlowComponentForm form)
at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.DataFlowUI.DataFlowComponentUI.EditImpl(IWin32Window parentControl)
at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.DataFlowUI.DataFlowComponentUI.Edit(IWin32Window parentWindow, Variables variables, Connections connections)
```

It worked fine last week and I don't think I changed anything since then. Any suggestions?

Comment: below link might be useful http://www.cla5h.com/web-service-task-excuting-error-method-not-found.html

Comment: What provider are you using for your OLE DB Connection Manager?

Comment: @billinkc In the project where I had found the error, I was using a Microsoft OLE DB Provider for AS/400. But I tested it on other providers too and it's the same for all.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I ran into this same issue on a computer with Visual Studio 2010 (although I'm sure VS2012 will have the same resolution). I installed Visual Studio 2015 and then started receiving this error when I tried to open an ADO NET source or an OLD DB Source in VS2010. I found that my DatatransformationServices files in the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies` had become corrupt. I copied all **`Microsoft.DatatransformationServices`** files from a computer where VS2010 was working to my local computer, folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies`.

You can use a command like the following from cmd to do so:

```
copy /Y "\\\GoodComputerName\C$\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.*.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\"
```

I then added the assemblies to my cache using the following commands in cmd (just change the directory with gacutil to your newest version in the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin` and change the folder for Visual Studio to the folder for the version in which you are receiving the error):

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools"
gacutil /if "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.DatatransformationServices.DataFlowUI.dll"
gacutil /if "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.DLL"
gacutil /if "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.DTSExecUI.Controls.dll"
gacutil /if "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Interfaces.dll"
gacutil /if "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration.DLL"
gacutil /if "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Wizards.DLL"
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. I had the same issue with SSDT 2012 after installing SSDT 2015 on top of it and this solution worked for me.

Comment: Second that, this is the solution.  Ran into this issue after patching and solved it using the steps above.  Much appreciated GaryS.

Comment: Agreed - this is a better solution

Comment: This resolved the issue.  I had the exact same error, probably caused from installing multiple versions of Visual Studio/SSDT.  For me it specifically occurred when I uninstalled VS2010 after installing later versions (2015, 2017).  I then needed to reinstall VS2010 + SSDT and was met with this error.

Comment: Helped me after installing SSDT2015 and VS 2015 over existing VS2012.
Except I did not copy the files - only had to runGACUTIL:
1. Opened VS2012 Native Tools Command Prompt as Administror
2. Ran GACUTIL /if Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.DLL
gacutil /if Microsoft.DatatransformationServices.DataFlowUI.dll

Comment: This solution worked for me.  Then two days later, the problem was back.  This time I closed down VS, opened again, and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 3):

I just fixed the same problem with CCleaner free version by fixing broken registry entries.

For me, the problem occurred in SQL Server Data Tools 2012 which uses Visual Studio 2010 after installing multiple versions of SSDT including the 2015 Preview.

Opening any OLEDB source component raised the missing DLL error for C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.DatatransformationServices.DataFlowUI.dll

The solvusoft.com site linked by GoldBishop provided useful information about the problem but recommends using their dubious product to fix it. Please read this thread on the [Norton community site](http://community.norton.com/forums/solvusoft-winthruster-download-deleted-norton-360) regarding Solvusoft and how it uses RegCleanPro.

Before using a tool like CCleaner, please research it. See who has rated it as a good product. While using it, check that it has backed up your registry entries (it does).

Answer (score 0):

Quick search for this topic, lead me to another site: http://www.solvusoft.com/en/files/missing-not-found-error/dll/windows/microsoft/msdn-disc-2729/microsoft-datatransformationservices-dataflowui-dll/
- This basically states the DLL/Registry is missing/corrupt

After reviewing the MSDN documentation, I assume this is from a Drag and Drop implementation?  Seems anything short of an environment DLL missing/corrupt, you may need to debug run the package to see exactly where the error is persisting.

Comment: The site does indeed describe my problem, but none of the options (except clean install, which I didn't do), fixed my problem. I guess there isn't an official site to download missing dll files?

Comment: There is no guarantee that the DLL file if download is a clean dll.  Better to just resinstall and make sure you have all the components available aftewards before releasing for use.  Sounds like you had a botched install/patch/upgrade and it corrupted the DLL from being used.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue on a computer with Visual Studio 2010 (although I'm sure VS2012 will have the same resolution). I installed Visual Studio 2015 and then started receiving this error when I tried to open an ADO NET source or an OLD DB Source in VS2010. I found that my DatatransformationServices files in the folder

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies 
had become corrupt. I copied all Microsoft.DatatransformationServices files from a computer where VS2010 was working to my local computer, folder

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
You can use a command like the following from cmd to do so:

copy /Y "\\GoodComputerName\C$\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.*.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\"

I then added the assemblies to my cache using the following commands in cmd (just change the directory with gacutil to your newest version in the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin and change the folder for Visual Studio to the folder for the version in which you are receiving the error):

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools"

gacutil /if "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.DatatransformationServices.DataFlowUI.dll"

gacutil /if "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.DLL"

gacutil /if "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.DTSExecUI.Controls.dll"

gacutil /if "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Interfaces.dll"

gacutil /if "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration.DLL"

gacutil /if "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Wizards.DLL"
```

This resolution worked for me so I hope it works for you also :)

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. Check the latest version in
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools`.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same using SSMS 2016. This is a known issue with July 2016 release.

I didn't have the issue initially, but was messing around with SMO.

Installing 16.5.3 fixed the issue:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

Sources:
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2925257